# Множественная вставка в pivot таблицу

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите, как делать множественную вставку в pivot-таблицу?
Есть две таблицы: `categories, attributes`
и связывающая таблица `attribute_category`

```
    Schema::create('attribute_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('attribute_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('attribute_id')->references('id')->on('attributes')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

**App\Models\Category**

```
class Category extends Model {
    public function attribute(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Attribute');
    }
}
```

**App\Models\Attribute**

```
class Attribute extends Model {
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category');
    }
}
```

**controller**

```
$attributes = ['attrib1','attrib2','attrib3'];
Category::get()->each(function($category) use($attributes){
    Attribute::whereIn('name', $attributes)->each(function($attribute) use($category){
        $category->attribute()->attach($attribute);
    });
});
```

В результате получаются примерно такие запросы:

```
"insert into `attribute_category` (`attribute_id`, `category_id`) values (?, ?)"
"insert into `attribute_category` (`attribute_id`, `category_id`) values (?, ?)"
"insert into `attribute_category` (`attribute_id`, `category_id`) values (?, ?)"
"select * from `attributes` where `name` in (?, ?, ?) order by `attributes`.`id` asc limit 1000 offset 0"
"insert into `attribute_category` (`attribute_id`, `category_id`) values (?, ?)"
"insert into `attribute_category` (`attribute_id`, `category_id`) values (?, ?)"
"insert into `attribute_category` (`attribute_id`, `category_id`) values (?, ?)"
"select * from `attributes` where `name` in (?, ?, ?) order by `attributes`.`id` asc limit 1000 offset 0"
"insert into `attribute_category` (`attribute_id`, `category_id`) values (?, ?)"
"insert into `attribute_category` (`attribute_id`, `category_id`) values (?, ?)"
"insert into `attribute_category` (`attribute_id`, `category_id`) values (?, ?)"
```

Как можно сократить запросы?

Comment: Вполне можно использовать [DB::insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723865/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-from-a-single-query-using-eloquent-fluent) с массивом данных.

Comment: метод `sync` в `BelongsToMany` также делает множественные запросы, поэтому я соглашусь с @DanielProtopopov